# Running a stored procedure from Invoke-Sqlcmd

Tags: sql-server, powershell, stored-procedures

Can `sp_who2` be run as the query on PowerShell?

I know from

```
Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance 'DB001' -Query "sp_who2 'ADDOM\username';"
```

that '107' is a spid for this user. This execution of a stored procedure does not provide an opportunity to provide a column name alias using AS.

```
PS C:\> Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance 'DB001' -Query "sp_who2 '107';"
```

> Invoke-Sqlcmd: Duplicate column names are not permitted in SQL PowerShell. To repeat a column, use a column alias for the duplicate column in the format Column_Name AS New_Name.

```
PS C:\> $PSVersionTable.PSVersion.ToString()
7.2.5
```

Comment: Nope. It is an issue with the way that procedure was written. Never did understand why SPID is returned twice.

Comment: @SeanLange - I always guessed it was for the bad old days when horizontal real estate was limited and so having the SPID duplicated helped for when you'd scrolled to the right and the SPID column was no longer visible.

Comment: @BenThul yeah the comment in the code indicates that is the reason. "--Handy extra for right-scrolling users.". If only they had given the column a unique name.

Answer (score 2):

You can insert the results of a stored procedure into a table. It's verbose for powershell, but still manageable.

```
$cmd = @'
    drop table if exists #results;
    create table #results (
        SPID smallint NULL,
        Status VARCHAR(20) NULL,
        Login sysname NULL,
        HostName sysname NULL,
        BlkBy varchar(40) NULL,
        DBName sysname NULL,
        Command varchar(100) NULL,
        CPUTime bigint NULL,
        DiskIO bigint NULL,
        LastBatch varchar(20) NULL,
        ProgramName sysname NULL,
        RepeatedSPID smallint NULL,
        REQUESTID int NULL
    )
 
    insert into #results
    exec sp_who2 'yourlogin';

    select *
    from #results
'@

invoke-sqlcmd -ServerInstance . -Query $cmd;
```

Is that too much to type all at the commandline? For sure. Wrap that in a function (along with the ability to provide a parameter for the login) and throw it in your powershell profile.

Comment: I feared this would be the kind of workaround. I am using an AD login and it is reporting `ADDOM\username' is not a valid login or you do not have permission.` This user can run sp_who2 in SSMS successfully.

Comment: Off the top of my head, I can't think of why this approach would work in SSMS and not through Invoke-SqlCmd. I'd start with normal security/permissions-related investigations (i.e. doing `select suser_sname()` to verify that I'm running as who I think I am, etc).